# Rachmaninoff Prelude G minor progression involves V chord instead of v chord

Tags: chord-theory, analysis

Why does Rachmaninoff seem to use a major V chord instead of a minor v chord in the attached measure (7th from the end) of his Prelude in G minor?

The progression seems to be
i-VI7-idim7-v-V-(in next measure)i.

(I don't think I got the type of the diminished chord right)

What is the meaning/point of the V chord? Is this common? I'd expect a v chord.

[image: Rachmaninoff prelude G minor, measure 80, final chord]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This 7th measure from the end (Bar 80) of Sergei Rachmaninoff's Prelude in G Minor, Op. 23, No. 5 is right after one of the loudest passages in the entire piece, and one near the end of the piece at that:

[image: Prelude in G Minor, Op. 23, No. 5 - Bars 72-80]

Not only is this near-concluding passage loud, it is tense, with chromatic passing tones (or at least melodic passages) aplenty. The 9th to 8th measures from the end of the piece - the last 2 measures of the passage - even use a strident and dissonant Pedal G -> ♭II -> Pedal G -> ii half-diminished 7 -> vii°7 -> V(♭)13 chord progression (ignoring inversions)!

With a passage like that hot on Bar 80's heels, you deserve an emotional release.

Bar 80 provides the start of the winding down and emotional release of this Rachmaninoff Prelude, with fewer unique chords and more resolved-sounding chords than in the previous measures (not to mention quieter music). **V7 is used instead of v because** (possibly among other reasons) **V7's use of the leading tone provides a stronger, up-by-semitone resolution to the tonic (i) chord than v's use of the subtonic** (which would have to go up a whole tone instead to resolve to the nearest note in the tonic chord), and this coda aims to provide a sound resolution for the piece.

Compared to what came just before, the last 7 measures of the coda don't actually use that many unique chords, especially per measure on average:

[image: Prelude in G Minor, Op. 23, No. 5 - Bars 78-86]

...just the unique chords in their i -> Ger. Aug. 6 = VI7 -> vii°7/V -> V7 |-> i -> Ger. Aug. 6 = VI7 -> vii°7/V -> V7 |-> i -> III -> V7 |-> i -> III -> V |-> i -> V -> i -> V |-> i -> V -> i -> V |-> i chord progression (ignoring inversions).

I recall similarly using fewer unique chords and gravitating towards the tonic and V chords in the codas of my classical music pieces.

Answer (score 1):

Not only is the use of the V chord in minor common, it is the norm. Rachmaninoff uses it frequently throughout the piece: for example, measure 5

[image: m. 5 V chord]

and measure 15

[image: m. 15 V chord]

among many others.

The purpose of this — more specifically, the purpose of the raised leading tone — is to intensify the pull toward the tonic and has been a cornerstone of tonal and pre-tonal composition for several hundred years.

Its usage at the end of the piece is to drive home G minor as the home-base tonality.

Comment: Thank you, both answers were super informative.

Answer (score 0):

This is Eb major chord with G in Bass (VI36 resp. 36): 1st inversion of Eb= 3rd  is Basstone. The theory says the third in the bass is so strong that  it shouldn’t be doubled and it would be better be missed in the upper voices.

This rule of harmony was not used in times of Bach, Händel or Haydn, as a statistical research of Diether de la Motte has shown.

[image]

Comment: Related to this answer of mine: https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/84381/should-one-double-the-thirds-or-the-fifth-in-chords

Comment: FYI: The question has been updated in such a way that your answer no longer applies as currently written.